# Windows doesn't recognise first partition on SD Card

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, sd-card

I have a 32 GB SD Card that I bak my files up to. Recently I've dual booted my Windows 7 laptop with Ubuntu, and I wanted to use [timeshift](http://www.howtogeek.com/206491/how-to-restore-your-ubuntu-linux-system-to-its-previous-state/) to back up my Ubuntu system.

Timeshift requires an `ext` based file system, so I opened gParted and shrunk the existing `FAT32` partition on my SD Card down to use half the drive, and created a new `ext4` partition to use with ubuntu.

It was working well in ubuntu, but I've found that Windows no longer recognises the file system on the first partition correctly. Here's a screenshot from the "Disk Management" section of the "Computer Management" console:

[image: SD Card Partitions]

How can I get windows to recognise the first partition as FAT32? Ubuntu recosnises *both* partitions correctly. Windows should, in theory, recognise the first partition as `FAT32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice that first partition is RAW now.  It is no longer formatted as FAT32.  When you shrunk it the partition information didn't go with it, has been deleted, or corrupted.  What I would do is see if Linux can read it.  If it can, copy your data off on the Linux box (or somewhere else), and reformat the RAW partition as FAT32 on the Windows box.  Then move the data from the Linux box (or wherever you put it) back on to the FAT32 partition.  Windows infrequently has problems with other OS's/applications changing things.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The strange thing is that Ubuntu seems perfectly cool with it and lets me read the partition as normal....! I'll give this a try. thanks!

Comment: Also if you want to keep your partition as ext4 you can use `ext2fsd [http://www.ext2fsd.com]` to mount on windows it supports almost all windows version.